# Error: Expected a function body or '=>'. Try adding {}

Tags: flutter, dart

dart "c:\Users\yigit\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Tutorial Dart\13.02.2023\13.02.2023.dart"
../../Tutorial%20Dart/13.02.2023/13.02.2023.dart:8:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'Vehicle' is missing implementations for these members:

- Vehicle.info
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class Vehicle {
^^^^^^^
../../Tutorial%20Dart/13.02.2023/13.02.2023.dart:15:8: Context: 'Vehicle.info' is defined here.
void info();
^^^^

```
// Higher order and Lexure Closure
Function plusWith(num x) {
  return (num y) => x + y;
}

class Vehicle {
  String brand = "";
  String model = "";
  int horsePower = 0;

  Vehicle(this.brand, this.model, this.horsePower);
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  Car(String brand, String model, int horsePower)
      : super(brand, model, horsePower);
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
  Motorcycle(String brand, String model, int horsePower)
      : super(brand, model, horsePower);
}

main(List<String> args) {
//Lambda Functions

  var func1 = (int v1) => v1 * 3;
  print(func1(5));

// Lexure Closure Cont;

  var addNum1 = plusWith(5);
  var addNum2 = plusWith(7);

  print(addNum1(2)); // Output 5 + 2 = 7
  print(addNum2(3)); // Output 7 + 3 = 10

Vehicle car = Car(brand: "Golf", model: "VW", horsePower: 150);
  Vehicle car2 = Car(model: "A4", brand: "Audi", horsePower: 150);
  Vehicle moto = Motorcycle(brand: "MT-25", model: "Yamaha", horsePower: 37);
  Vehicle moto2 =
      Motorcycle(brand: "Super-Tenere", model: "Yamaha", horsePower: 127);

  List<Vehicle> allVehicle = [car, car2, moto, moto2];
/*   var list1 = List<Vehicle>.filled(5, Vehicle("", "", 0));
  var listFrom = List<Vehicle>.from(allVehicle); */
  var listOf = List<Vehicle>.of(allVehicle.whereType<Car>());

  print(listOf);
/*   print(listFrom); */
}
```

Nothing i've been tried

Comment: Your code doesn't show this `void info()`. Also your code uses named arguments for Car and Motorcycle while their class doesn't have that. Please show us the code that actually gives your error because this can't be it. Also all code related to `plusWith` doesn't seem to be relevant at all. Also you tagged [tag:flutter]  but this is just about dart

Answer (score 1):

Just make **Car** and **Motorcycle** variables required as follows:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
  Car({required String brand,required  String model,required  int horsePower})
      : super(brand, model, horsePower);
}
   
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
  Motorcycle({required String brand, required String model, required int horsePower})
      : super(brand, model, horsePower);
}
```